# AngularJS filter not work in input field required

Tags: forms, angularjs, field

this work

```
<input type="text" aaa="{{field.isRequired | requiredx}}" ng-model="field.input.model">
```

output

```
<input type="text" aaa="required" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="field.input.model">
```

but this not work

```
<input type="text" required="{{field.isRequired | requiredx}}" ng-model="field.input.model">
```

output

```
<input type="text" required="{{field.isRequired | requiredx}}" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" ng-model="field.input.model">
```

....

Edit, add filter:

```
angular.module('appFilters', []).filter('requiredx', function() {
return function(input) {
    return input ? 'required' : '';
};
```

});
Anyone have an idea how make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-required, you can't set HTML5's required attribute like that. Try this:

`<input type="text" ng-required="(field.isRequired | requiredx)" ng-model="field.input.model">`