# How to add validation on AngularJS directive element?

Tags: html, angularjs, kendo-ui

I have kendo validation on one div that is working , another div i have AngularJS directive but i could not implement validation and make it requried field. How can i make required field like i have in Business process name ?

so far tried code...

div1.html

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 fieldHeight">
            <label for="name" class="col-md-5 required">Business Process Name:</label>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
                ng-model="processDTO.processLongName"
                placeholder="Process Name" maxlength="256" name="processName"
                data-required-msg="Business Process Name is required" required><span
                class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="processName"></span>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 fieldHeight">
            <label for="countries" class="col-md-5 required">Geographic Locations:</label>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div multiselect-dropdown-tree ng-model="nonPersistentProcess.geoLocations" disable-children="true"  options="treeviewOptions"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663094/angularjs-filter-not-work-in-input-field-required Hope this helps!

Comment: but i am using kendo validation..

Comment: Which div cannot have validation? Your html page is ignoring required? What does your app.js file look like?